# AWS network load balancer configuration for Tomcat hosts automatic failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, network-load-balancer

I have a network load balancer setup with a TCP listener on port 443, and in my target group I have two UI EC2 instances, both running tomcat. I would like for the users to be directed to second UI node if the Tomcat service on the first UI node is down. Both registered targets (First and second UI nodes) are healthy and the NLB is active. To test, I put the NLB DNS name into my browser, it redirects to the first UI node. I stop Tomcat on that node and refresh my browser, but the connection does not get redirected to the second UI node. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Here are all the config values, which ones do you recommend me to change and to what value?

```
Protocol: TCP 
Port: traffic 
port Healthy 
Threshold: 2 
Unhealthy Threshold: 2 
Timeout: 10 Interval: 30
```

Thank you

Comment: Given  your health check settings, it will take a minute or two for the target group to flag the UI node as unhealthy and stop sending traffic to it. Did you wait that long? Did you see the node get flagged as unhealthy in the target group after waiting a few minutes?

Comment: Yes, after a couple of minutes, it reports the host as being unhealthy and when I refresh the page where I had browsed to the NLB DNS name, it will come up again which shows it started to route the traffic to the second host. Is there any way we improve the speed of this failover?

Comment: That is working as expected then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are the numbers correct or I have to change something so the failover happens quicker?

Comment: I can't tell you if the numbers are "correct" or not. They are what they are. The timeout and Interval numbers are in seconds, so if you want it to time out quicker, reduce those, and/or reduce the Unhealthy Threshold value to 1.

Comment: I have already tried that and got an error. If I set both timeout and Unhealthy Threshold value to 1, I get an error saying: "valid min value: 2". If I set them both to 2, I get a different error: "Custom health check timeouts are not supported for health checks for target groups with the TCP protocol". Not sure what I should do

Comment: I think you may be able to reduce the Interval value. It looks like your other values are already at the minimum level. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

Comment: @MarkB - I tried to change the interval value and got this error: "You cannot change the health check interval for a target group with the TCP protocol", so what do you recommend I should do? Thank you in advance

Comment: It doesn't sound like you can do anything else. Like I said, it's already working as expected.

Comment: @MarkB - I did some research and apparently, I had to delete that target group and re-created it to be able to select a different interval value. This time, it let me change the interval (had two options, 10 and 30 and I picked 10). So now my number are: Healthy Threshold: 2, Unhealthy Threshold: 2, Timeout: 10 and interval: 10. would you say it's going to improve the failover time? Thank you

Comment: You changed the time interval from 30 seconds to 10 seconds. So yes, it will obviously fail over faster now.